# Least Common Multiple and Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Prove that if $\mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}( a, b) + \gcd(a, b) = a+b$,
$a$ divides $b$ or $b$ divides $a$.

This problem seemed simple at first, however I cannot figure out a way to prove this. If I assume both parts of the statement, I can show it is true, but that is not a valid proof method.

Comment: ... or $b$ divides $a$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have updated it

Comment: Please use LaTeX notation like this: `$\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$` which typesets as $\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$. Oh, and this example could be understood as a hint.

Comment: @ccorn It hasn't seemed to help me

Comment: ccorn's hint is: show that $\gcd(a,b)$ and $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ are roots of $x^2-(a+b)x+ab$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$d = \gcd(a, b)$,
and let
$a = dA$
and
$b = dB$.

Then,
since
$\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)
=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}
=\frac{ABd^2}{d}
=ABd
$,
$d+ABd
=Ad+Bd
$,
so
$1+AB
=A+B
$
or
$0
=AB-A-B+1
=(A-1)(B-1)
$.

Therefore
either $A=1$
or $B=1$.
If $A=1$,
then
$a = dA = d$
divides
$b = dB$.
Similarly,
if $B = 1$,
$b$ divides $a$.

Comment: Ah, Mr. (or, more likely, Dr. Prof.) Hardy. You are definitely a smooth operator(name). Me, I'm too lazy - I will use $a, b, c$ for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and, in general, anything to minimize keystrokes.